# How to fix issue regarding pkpass not working after dragging to ios simulator?

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

I am currently creating a passcard for my app but unfortunately, it is not working. Passcard is not showing in the simulator when dragging it or event downloading it from my email. My `pass.json` codes are below.

```
"formatVersion" : 1,
"passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.com.example",
"serialNumber" : "0000000",
"teamIdentifier" : "xxxxxxxx",
"barcode" : {

"message" : "123456789",
"format" : "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
"messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1",
 },

"organizationName" :  "companyname",
"description" : "companytagline",
"logoText" : "companyname",
"foregroundColor" : "rgb(255,255,255)",
"backgroundColor":  "rgb(0,100,0)",
"generic" : {
"auxiliaryFields" : [
{
    "key" : "patientName",
    "label" : "NAME",
    "value" : "Retail Pharmacy 1, Test Patient"
    },

{
    "key" : "gender",
    "label" : "GENDER",
    "value" : "Female"
    }
],

}

}
```

This is what I have in my **Terminal**

```
hopprlabs-iMac:Desktop developer1$ ./signpass -p healthpass.raw/
 2019-02-19 10:10:39.483 signpass[2096:231781] {
".DS_Store" = df2fbeb1400acda0909a32c1cf6bf492f1121e07;
"Icon.png" = 295cb779e5e185efefd6c5e9a2a94c3352e51b2a;
"Icon@2x.png" = 987db966ddc28a72d6bfd15a6565d191be06d0f0;
"pass.json" = 3e66cf17f758939547932654c3394e42470d1c94;
"thumbnail.png" = 2a616d4490d1e12d81ddb0610df6b992ad79aeca;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a copy of your Pkpass file?

Comment: where could i attached the pkpass file?

Comment: You could share via Dropbox/Gdrive/Onedrive etc. You could also email it to me directly (tomas@coldbear.co.uk)? I'll post any findings here.

Comment: @TomasMcGuinness sent to your email. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for emailing that through. Having looked at the package, it seems there is a problem with your icon file.

The iPhone reports this error like this:

Invalid data error reading pass pass.com./0000000. Pass does not contain icon.png/icon@2x.png/icon@3x.png

I suggest making your icon file names lower case, so icon.png instead of Icon.png. 
I would also include the @3x size file too.

Comment: No problem. I will add this check to my pass validation project (https://pkpassvalidator.azurewebsites.net/)